# Disable horizontal scroll in a subview of UIScrollView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiscrollview

I have 3 `UIScrollViews`, call them `A`, `B`, and `C`.

`A` is a Paging scrollview, that has many `B` scrollviews added as subviews (the pages).
`B` only scrolls vertically.
`C` is a scrollview added as a subview to a `UIView` that is added as a subview to `B`.

The functionality I am trying to achieve is:

Disallow paging of `A` if a horizontal scroll is happening within the `UIView` that is housing `C`.  However, still allow the vertically scrolling of `B`.

Comment: I set up triply-nested scroll views in a test app just the way you described: a top-level horizontally-paging scroll view with 3 pages, each page containing a vertically-scrolling scroll view, and each vertical scroll view containing a horizontally scrolling scroll view.  Everything works as desired under the iOS 5.0 and iOS 6.0 simulators. Dragging vertically anywhere scrolls the vertical scroll view.  Dragging horizontally outside of the innermost scroll view scroll between pages.  Dragging horizontally inside the innermost scroll view scroll that scroll view and doesn't change pages.

Answer (score 0):

Implement the `- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView*)scrollView` to find out which scrollview is scrolling and then check `contentOffset` property of scrollview to determine the  scrolling position of scrollviews. `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` delegate can be used to detect the end of scrolling.

for eg:-

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView*)scrollView {
    if (scrollView == C) {
       //disable scrolling of A
    }
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if (scrollView == C) {
        //enable scrolling of A
    }
}
```

Based on your exact requirement, you can use these two delegates and `contentOffset` of that particular scrollview to get the desired effect.